# Opportunity Line Items not generating

Tags: cpq, steelbrick

I have a Product that is set up as a CPQ Product. It has options/features etc. Just like any other product set up in my org. I create an opportunity, create a quote and set that quote as Primary. I then go into the quote line editor using Add/Edit Products. Pricing populates great, and then I click on save and we exit out of the Quote Line editor and now we are in the Quote page. All the quote lines are in there with the right pricing and everything. Now when I click on the Opportunity, the opportunity Line Items are not there. I always assumed that, that would happen automatically, and it happens with all other products save for this one, somewhere there is some setting that prevents the Opp Lines to be generated, I am just wondering what that is.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore question. There was a custom field 'Exclude from Opportunity' which was checked. This prevented the line item from showing up

Comment: CPQ has way too many configurable fields eh